# NFS mount a directory from server node to client node

Tags: linux, centos, mount, nfs

In one of my assignments on CentOS 7, I am trying to NFS mount /home directory from management node to client node. 
I have given the commands I have tried below.

I tried to disable firewall, but it's asking for password which I don't have, and so it didn't work. Then I made changes in the exports file as below, but nothing to my avail. PFB the commands I ran:

```
[user@node-1 ~]$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/key node-2
Last login: Wed Sep 19 12:56:36 2018 from 192.18.0.3
[user@node-2 ~]$ sudo mount -t nfs 192.18.0.3:/home /home          
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.18.0.3:/home
[user@node-2 ~]$ exit
logout
Connection to node-2 closed.
[user@node-1 ~]$ systemctl disable firewalld
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files ===
Authentication is required to manage system service or unit files.
Authenticating as: Cloud User (user)
Password:
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Failed to execute operation: Access denied
[user@node-1 ~]$ sudo vi /etc/exports
```

The changes made in the exports file are as:

```
/home 192.18.0.*(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

And then I tried updating the changes but got another error

```
[user@node-1 ~]$ exportfs -ra
exportfs: could not open /var/lib/nfs/.etab.lock for locking: errno 13 
(Permission denied)
exportfs: can't lock /var/lib/nfs/etab for writing
```

Can anyone help me mount the /home directory from the management server to client server, please?

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I'm afraid that you need root permission to run exportfs. Your user doesn't seem to have sufficient rights.

Answer (score 2):

`192.18.0.*` is not a valid ip or subnet. Try `192.18.0.0/24` instead.

- Note: the  192.18.0.0 - 192.18.194.255 ip range belongs to Oracle Corporation. Don't use it unless you're a worker at oracle.

Comment: calvin probably did not type the subnet correctly. I guess, it was meant to be 192.168.0.0/24.

Comment: `Last login: Wed Sep 19 12:56:36 2018 from 192.18.0.3` so it probably really is this subnet.

Answer (score 0):

To check what are the allowed IP networks run this command in node-1:

```
$ showmount -e localhost
```

or this in node-2

```
$ showmount -e node-1
```

You should see the IP networks actually allowed to mount each of the NFS exported directories in node-1.